# git push going to wrong port number

Tags: git, gitlab

I have installed GitLab on a different machine which is in the local network. Intially, i had configured the server to run on port 8888 but later I changed it to 80. But then when I am trying to clone or push to the gitlab with the following, its failing and seems like its trying to connect to port 8888 still. When I visit gitlab using a browser it works fine. I am wondering where I could be making mistake.

```
git push -u origin master
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.1.0/net/http.rb:879:in `initialize': Connection refused - connect(2)   for "host.domain.edu" port 8888 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to edit your `.git/config` file to update your `origin` remote, to no longer use port 8888.

You can also use `git remote set-url`, but then you'd have to know the full correct URL.